# TableView-Like UICollectionView Layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionview, that can switch between 2 layouts. One layout is like a regular flow layout, auto-sizing the items in width and height. The other one should be a tableview-like layout, with a fixed width of the items, but autosizing their height.

I have managed to implement the two layouts using `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath)`, but only with a fixed item size. So I'd like to take full advantage of self-sizing cells, if possible without implementing the said delegate method.

How can I best auto-size the cells while forcing them to be full width for tableview-like layout?

Comment: Why not have a table view also and switch between the two?

Comment: because switching layouts in a single uicollectionview allows for transition animation between the layouts

Comment: this is interesting: https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZUtils/tree/master/RZUtils/Components/RZCollectionTableView

Comment: Probably in iOS 11 we'll get a `UICollectionViewTableLayout` from Apple, internally it's already there: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/the-case-for-deprecating-uitableview/

Answer (score -2):

Our custom layout must be invalidated when the collection view’s width changes but is not affected by scrolling. Fortunately, the collection view passes its new bounds to the shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange: method. This enables us to compare the view’s current bounds to the new value and only return YES if we have to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
CGRect oldBounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
if (CGRectGetWidth(newBounds) != CGRectGetWidth(oldBounds)) {
    return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Changes from one collection view layout to another can be animated in a similar manner. When sent a `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` method, the collection view will query the new layout for the new layout attributes of the cells and then animate each cell (identified by the same index path in the old and the new layout) from its old to its new attributes. You don’t have to do a thing.

Comment: but how can i have self-sizing cells, and have them forced to full-width for tableview-like layout?

Comment: by making two layout subclass files.

Comment: could you post full code? i'm struggling with the auto-sizing part.

Comment: This may help you... http://zappdesigntemplates.com/collectionview-flow-layout-from-grid-to-list-layout/

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it uses a fixed item height while i want to use auto-sizing for that

Comment: @fabb Can you tell me in detail about your subviews, that you are showing in tableLayout?

Comment: its a simple collectionviewcell with an image on the left, and text on the right (stackview horizontal) for table layout, and with image on top, and same text below (stackview vertical) for flow layout.